# I am trying to change the properties of a table cell with javascript and have found my suggestions but I can't seem to get them to work

Tags: javascript

I have a table where each row has 7 input columns.  I want to disable the 3rd column of each row and change the text color to red.

```
function changeCells() {
  var table = document.getElementById("tbl");
  for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    var tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i];
    var td = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
    td.style.color = 'red';
    td.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

I can change the background with:

`td.style.backgroundColor = 'red';`

but not the text color.

The input column is also not disabled. Not sure why this code doesn't work.

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML.

Comment: Table cells don't have a disabled property. Form elements do.

Comment: *the **input** column* ... is never changed by your code... just its surrounding (?) td ...

Comment: Sounds like you have input elements inside you `td`s. Please provide html so that we can help you better.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the rest of the CSS and HTML, it's difficult to tell, but it sounds like you have other CSS setting the text color (assuming the background color changes works as you described). You can add the `!important` modifier via Javascript to test this for certain:

```
td.style.setProperty("color", "red", "important");
```

If it takes that, then something else wasn't letting you change the color. Ideally, you would instead add a class to the `<td>` element, and then you can control what it looks like via pure CSS.

In JS:

```
td.className = 'highlight-cell';
```

Then in CSS:

```
.highlight-cell {
    color: red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `td` element cannot be disabled. You need to target the `input` element within it. Here is a working example of what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/0xk99dxr/

And the relevant code being added:

```
var inputElement = td.querySelector("input");
    inputElement.style.color = 'red';
    inputElement.disabled = true;
```

Comment: Why not just `var inputElement = td.querySelector("input");`?

Comment: Thank you.  This is exactly what I needed.  - Ron

Answer (score -1):

To change the text color inside every row of third column, use the following line of code in css file.

```
#tbl tr td:nth-child(3){color: red}
```

Table cells don't have a disabled property.

Comment: and wheres the *answer*?

Comment: and the OP says that this code is already being used and isn't working.

Comment: You can use the above code to change the text color to red on every 3rd column of each row.